# Web scraping relevant information from soup file

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this particular url to obtain information on branch/atm name and location address.

```py
url="https://www.bankmayapada.com/en/contactus/location-information"
```

However, the soup file I get is pretty confusing and I am unable to figure out how to extract the required information.

The information I need is Branch/Atm Name and its corresponding address. Right now, I am just figuring out the structure of the soup file.

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that table's data with a single `POST` request. Fun fact, no payload required!

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.post("https://myapps.bankmayapada.com/frontend/IN/lokasi.aspx").text
rows = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("tr", {"class": "dxgvDataRow"})

branch_location_data = []
for row in rows:
    province, area, location = row.find_all("td")
    branch_location_data.append(
        [
            province.getText(strip=True),  # province column
            area.getText(strip=True),  # area column
            location.find("b").getText(strip=True),  # Branch name
            " ".join(
                d.getText() for d in location.find_all("div")  # branch address
                if not d.getText().startswith(("Tel", "Fax"))  # skipping Phone & Fax info
            ),
        ]
    )
for branch in branch_location_data:
    print(branch)
```

Output:

```
['DKI JAKARTA', 'Jakarta Barat', 'Kantor Capem Citra Garden 2', 'Rukan Citra Niaga Blok A-7 Jl. Utan Jati - Kalideres Jakarta - DKI  Jakarta']
['DKI JAKARTA', 'Jakarta Barat', 'Kantor Capem Puri Indah', 'Jl. Puri Indah Raya Blok I No. 2 Jakarta 11610 - DKI  Jakarta']
['DKI JAKARTA', 'Jakarta Barat', 'Kantor Capem Pasar Pagi Asemka', 'Jl. Pasar Pagi No. 84 Jakarta - DKI  Jakarta']
['DKI JAKARTA', 'Jakarta Barat', 'Kantor Capem Tanjung Duren', 'Jl. Tanjung Duren No. 91 B Jakarta 11470 - DKI  Jakarta']
['DKI JAKARTA', 'Jakarta Barat', 'Kantor Capem Meruya', 'Jl. Meruya Ilir Raya No. 82 G Jakarta - DKI  Jakarta']
['DKI JAKARTA', 'Jakarta Barat', 'Kantor Capem Jembatan Lima', 'Jl. KH Moch. Mansyur No. 24 A Jakarta - DKI  Jakarta']
and so on...
```

Comment: TIL! Do you mind expanding a bit (or referring to some sources) about `Fun fact, no payload required!`?

Comment: Well, honestly, all I did was I took a look at the traffic in the Developer Tool and inspected the request that was responsible for the table. In the `Headers` tab it's just a wall of text and I thought, what the heck, let me just send a `POST` without all that junk. What could go wrong? Nothing! I got back the entire table along some other stuff. No payload, no nothing. It just worked.

Comment: "https://myapps.bankmayapada.com/frontend/IN/lokasi.aspx" has the default selection of branch names. But I want to do the same exercise for atm names and addresses as well. The url doesn't change when I select the atm option. How can I do the same for atms?

Comment: Wow! It never occurred to me to try that! I just looked at the `GET` headers' "wall of text" and was about to say "forget it" when you posted your answer. I'm going to try this on a regular basis now... Thanks for the idea!